# Execute Twig function in PHP

Tags: php, twig

Is it possible to execute a Twig function in PHP ? For example, the twig function path() is used in our project to generate the URL of a page, I would like to be able to access this in PHP as well. Is this possible ?

Comment: Could you link the documentation of the `path()` function? I can't find something useful.

Comment: I wish I could.... can't find it as well. It just works :D

Comment: All the TWIG functions are pre-defined in PHP (I mean in fact TWIG functions are php functions which are leveraged in TWIG). e.g. `path` in TWIG and Symfony equals to `$this->generateUrl()`

Answer (score 0):

No. I'd recommend to go the other way around and rewrite the function in php. Then use them also in twig with [functions](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions) or [filters](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters).

Comment: I thought about that too, but I can't find the path() function... I guess it's default Twig stuff, very useful one, that's why I would like to access it in PHP instead of reinventing the wheel